# Rails: How to save uploaded image in directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, save

I want to save uploaded image in directory, So, I send multipart request to rails server, and get it.

but I don't know save image in directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self resolved.

rails have "pulblic" directory  (APP.root/public)

you can save here.

And you can access directly